# Discord.py | Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python

```
@bot.command(name='ownerinfo')
async def ownerinfo(ctx: commands.Context):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='DUCKY | Owner Info', color=0x00FFD4)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://url')
    embed.add_field(name="Info", value="text here", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="DUCKY HELPER BOT | -help")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

I have a command thats exactly the same as my other commands, but I get this error:

```
`AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'command'`
```

I looked online, and I didnt find any fixes. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

do you have a command that's called `bot` right before the `ownerinfo` command? if so, change the function name to `_bot` and `name="bot"` inside the command constructor `@bot.command(name="bot")`

```py
bot = commands.Bot(...)


@bot.command()
async def first_command(ctx, ...):
    # do something


@bot.command()
async def bot(ctx, ...):
    # do something
# your previous declared variable was overridden by a Command function

@bot.command() # error, because it thinks you are using the `Command` function 'bot' instead of your Bot instance
async def ownerinfo(ctx, ...):
    # do something



bot.run()
```

just change your function name:

```py
@bot.command(name="bot")
async def _bot(ctx, ...):
    # do something
# it's not overriding anymore
```